# Use Array in Bootstrap SelectPicker - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use values that exist in an array as the values for a Bootstrap SelectPicker. I'm not sure where to get started to loop through the array for the values.
I have the SelectPicker with values plugged in manually, like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
  </head>

  <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true">
    <option data-subtext="Solar Install - Hartsville">Printing Dimensions</option>
    <option data-subtext="Frankfurt to Karsruhe - Dry">Tubulard</option>
    <option data-subtext="Jasper to Littlefield - Flatbed">General Mills</option>
  </select>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

</html>
```

Instead of manually listing all values, because it will be dynamic, I'd like to pull the values from this array. **dealName** would be the subtext and **accountName** would be the value.

```
const dealArray="[
    {
        "dealName": "Solar Install - Hartsville",
        "accountName": "Printing Dimensions"
    },
    {
        "dealName": "Frankfurt to Karsruhe - Dry",
        "accountName": "Tubulard"
    },
    {
        "dealName": "Jasper to Littlefield - Flatbed",
        "accountName": "General Mills"
    }
]"
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first.  You forgot to put in the `<body>` tag.  My example includes it.  But using jQuery, here is one way you could dynamically include the data like you're asking.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" id="targetSelect"></select>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.1/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

  <script>
    const dealArray = [{
        "dealName": "Solar Install - Hartsville",
        "accountName": "Printing Dimensions"
      },
      {
        "dealName": "Frankfurt to Karsruhe - Dry",
        "accountName": "Tubulard"
      },
      {
        "dealName": "Jasper to Littlefield - Flatbed",
        "accountName": "General Mills"
      }
    ]

    const parentTag = $('#targetSelect');

    dealArray.forEach(deal => {
      $(`<option data-subtext="${deal.dealName}">${deal.accountName}</option>`).appendTo(parentTag);
    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```